# SQL UPDATE query with GROUP BY and HAVING SUM clause in one table

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to build a query that executes a SET command in the same table due to a sum = 0 for a stock column. There are columns id, parent_id, stock and active. id is always present, parent_id can be present and contains a value that will only appear once in id. However, it can appear multiple times in parent_id. stock should only be evaluated for the rows that correspond to the same parent_id; a sum should be formed and evaluated here. If sum = 0, active must now be set to 0 in the active column of the "Parent" article - origin of the currently evaluated parent_id in id. I have tried several approaches, nothing leads to the right result.

```
UPDATE product AS b1, (
   SELECT HEX(`parent_id`) AS par_id, SUM(stock) AS total_stock
   FROM product
   GROUP BY par_id
   HAVING total_stock = 0 ) AS b2
SET b1.active = 0
WHERE b1.id = b2.par_id
```

#Query executed OK, 0 rows affected.

```
UPDATE product AS p1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT HEX(`parent_id`) AS par_id, SUM(stock) AS total_stock
FROM product AS p2 GROUP BY par_id HAVING total_stock = 0) AS ts
ON p1.id = ts.par_id
SET p1.active = 0
```

#Query executed OK, 0 rows affected.

```
UPDATE product
SET active = 0
FOR (SELECT parent_id FROM product GROUP BY parent_id HAVING SUM(stock) = 0) = id;
```

#Subquery returns more than 1 row

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Provide complete sample. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: Storing such calculated values too often ends up in data inconsistency. Consider creating a view instead. Or at least use triggers to keep the active values up-to-date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem

```
UPDATE product 
SET active = 0
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT parent_id FROM product   
    GROUP BY parent_id HAVING SUM(stock) = 0
);
```